# PhpStorm, UML diagrams and xmi-files

Tags: php, uml, phpstorm, xmi

I've a got huge PHP project with lots of classes, interfaces, abstraction layers... I need to see UML classes diagram. I'm wondering if PhpStorm can generate the one?

What I've found is that it is possible to view "diagram" for a single class: right click in File Explorer->Diargams->Show Diargram. Then I can add classes manually one by one.

But it is not exactly what I want. It will take eternity to add all classes. I don't need interactive diagram. I just need to see whole picture of my project.

Also, I've tried to use PHP_UML from PEAR. I've generated xmi-file using it. But several tools say that it is not valid(Sparx Enterprise Architect, ArgoUML and Visual Paradigm). 
And seems like PhpStorm can't open xmi-file(it opened as plain text file).

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to build UML diagram of whole project in PhpStorm?
2. Is it possible to make PhpStorm open xmi-file "properly"?
3. Is there any other tool which would show me ULM based on xmi.

Looks like very trivial problem by I can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Try to use the **Diagrams** context menu on the project root directory in the `Project View` tool window.
2. No.
3. Not my field, but [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) may help. Not sure why it didn't work for you. They also provide integration with IntelliJ IDEA, so you can contact them and ask if they have a plug-in for PhpStorm.